# Identify which sprite node was hit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I would like to be able to identify which exact target sprite node is hit when the user flings another sprite at a group of target sprites. Here is how I set up my sprites under the didMoveToView function (only including the relevant lines of code here)

```
let flingerTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "flinger")
flingerNode.position = CGPoint(x: 768, y: 440)
flingerNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: flingerTexture, size: flingerNode.size)
flingerNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
flingerNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Flinger
flingerNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Edge | PhysicsCategory.Bubble | PhysicsCategory.Ball
flingerNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
let rotationConstraint = SKConstraint.zRotation(SKRange(lowerLimit: -π/4, upperLimit: π/4))
flingerNode.constraints = [rotationConstraint]
addChild(flingerNode)

// -------------Setup targets---------------
let range: Range<Int> = 1...10
for numbers in range {
    let ballNode: BallNode = BallNode(imageNamed: "\(numbers)a")
    let positionX = CGFloat.random(min: size.width / 6, max: size.width * 5/6)
    let positionY = CGFloat.random(min: size.height * 4/9, max: size.height * 8/9)
    ballNode.position = CGPoint(x: positionX, y: positionY)
    ballNode.name = "Ball"
    ballNode.ballIndex = Int(numbers)
    index = ballNode.ballIndex
    ballNode.ballHit = false
    addChild(ballNode)

    ballNode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 100)
    ballNode.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    ballNode.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
    ballNode.physicsBody!.restitution = 0.5
    ballNode.physicsBody!.friction = 0.0
    ballNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball
    ballNode.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Ball | PhysicsCategory.Bubble | PhysicsCategory.Edge | PhysicsCategory.Flinger | PhysicsCategory.Wall
    ballNode.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.Flinger

    ballNode.userData = NSMutableDictionary()
    ballArray.append(ballNode.ballIndex)
}
```

I am able to detect the collision, but am unable to retrieve the additional userData that would identify which exact ballNode was struck. When I tried the following code, it only returns an output of "nil".

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
let collision = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
if collision == PhysicsCategory.Flinger | PhysicsCategory.Ball {
println(ballNode.userData)
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `PhysicsCategory.Flinger` is less than `PhysicsCategory.Ball`. Then in `didContactBegan` you can use this code.

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var body1 : SKPhysicsBody!
    var body2 : SKPhysicsBody!

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        body1 = contact.bodyA
        body2 = contact.bodyB
    }
    else  {
        body1 = contact.bodyB
        body2 = contact.bodyA
    }

    if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Flinger &&
        body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Ball {

            if let ballNode = body2.node {

                println(ballNode.userData)
            }
    }

}
```

The conditions have to be reversed if `PhysicsCategory.Flinger` is greater than `PhysicsCategory.Ball`.

```
if body1.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Ball &&
    body2.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Flinger {

        if let ballNode = body1.node {

            println(ballNode.userData)
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes @rakeshbs, your assumption is correct. But when I try the code you suggest, the output is 'Optional({ })'

Comment: And just to make sure I myself am not mistaken about that assumption, if I try the reversed condition anyway, the output is 'nil'.

Comment: I think the problem has something to do with how to add the userData for each node, as called within the moveToView function? But I don't know how to resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction @rakeshbs! Your didBeginContact method works - the problem was I wasn't adding the userData correctly. I resolved this by adding the following line to my didMoveToView function:

```
    ballNode.userData = ["ballNumber" : ballNode.ballIndex]
```